# Why is "get_slice" returning different values each time I ask?

Tags: c#, cassandra

I'm testing range slices and as an example I keep track of the prices of products, so my key is the product ID and the columns are dates, containing the price at that date.

I use a TimeUUIDType comparator in order to slice on the date, to get the price quotes on a given period.

Here's my schema :

```
{
    "ItemCode1": {
        "<timestamp>": { "name": "<timestamp>", "value": "<price>" },
        "<timestamp>": { "name": "<timestamp>", "value": "<price>" },
        ...
    },
    "ItemCode2": {
        "<timestamp>": { "name": "<timestamp>", "value": "<price>" },
        "<timestamp>": { "name": "<timestamp>", "value": "<price>" },
        ...
    }
}
```

My problem is that each time I query Cassandra, it gives me a slightly different list of columns (1-2 more or missing).
I use `get_slice` with a slice range with `ConsistencyLevel = ALL` and I even tried to repair the ColumnFamily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem actually came from the client side because I was using CassandraSharp's `TimeUuidNameOrValue` to define my slice boundaries.

But internally it generates a TimeUuid so my boundaries had a variable part, hence the variable results.